# Set y axis limits canvasjs

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set the minimum and maximum value on the y-axis of the following graph:

```
new CanvasJS.Chart(this.chartDivId, {
            zoomEnabled: true,                          //Client interactions: false para melhor desempenho
            animationEnabled: true,                     //Animacoes do grafico: false para melhor desempenho
            title: {
                text: "",                            //Sem titulo
                fontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",
                fontFamily: "Arial"
            },
            backgroundColor: "rgba(9, 9, 9)",           //Preto mofificado
            axisX: {
                labelFontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",  //Branco mofificado
                labelFontSize: 12                       //Tamanho da fonte
            },
            axisY: {
                labelFontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",  //Branco mofificado
                labelFontSize: 12                       //Tamanho da fonte
            },
            data: [
                {
                    type: "line",                       //Grafico de linhas
                    lineColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",   //Cor das letras
                    markerType: "none",                 //Circle se quiser uma marca nos pontos
                    dataPoints: []                      //Pontos do grafico
                }
            ]
        })
```

I need to change this setting and what it says on the website is not working.

Comment: I think you should remove "chart.js" tag because it seems to me related to anoher chart library, CanvasJs?

Answer (score 0):

```
new CanvasJS.Chart(this.chartDivId, {
        zoomEnabled: true,                          //Client interactions: false para melhor desempenho
        animationEnabled: true,                     //Animacoes do grafico: false para melhor desempenho
        title: {
            text: title,                            //Sem titulo
            fontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",
            fontFamily: "Arial"
        },
        backgroundColor: "rgba(9, 9, 9)",           //Preto mofificado
        axisX: {
            labelFontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",  //Branco mofificado
            labelFontSize: 12                       //Tamanho da fonte
        },
        axisY: {
            labelFontColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",  //Branco mofificado
            labelFontSize: 12,                      //Tamanho da fonte
            minimum: minY,
            maximum: maxY,
            interval: interval
        },
        data: [
            {
                type: "line",                       //Grafico de linhas
                lineColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102)",   //Cor das letras
                markerType: "none",                 //Circle se quiser uma marca nos pontos
                dataPoints: []                      //Pontos do grafico
            }
        ]
    });
```